# Rewriting a returned pointer to an output parameter

Tags: objective-c, function, pointers

I'm playing around with the openSSL library and it requires me to brush up on pointers, and I'm having difficulty.

I have a objective-c method:

```
-(unsigned char *)encryptTake1:(unsigned char *)input inputLength:(int)inLen outputLength:(int*)outLen;
```

It takes some data, encrypts it and returns a pointer to the data and the length of the data as an output parameter.

I want to change this so that the encrypted data is also handled as an output parameter and the return value is used to indicate success or failure. This is what I have:

```
-(int)encryptTake2:(unsigned char *)input inputLength:(int)inLen output:(unsigned char *)output outputLength:(int*)outLen;
```

This doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? I think the problem is that `(unsigned char *)` is the wrong. If `(unsigned char *)` is wrong then I presume I will also need to change how `output` is referenced within the method. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you are handling memory allocation.

What does `-encryptTake1:` return?  If it returns a newly allocated buffer that the caller must free then you would use `unsigned char**` in encryptTake2:

```
-(int)encryptTake2:(unsigned char *)input inputLength:(int)inLen output:(unsigned char **)outputPtr outputLength:(int*)outLen
{
    *outputPtr = malloc(1024);
    unsigned char* output = *outputPtr;
    strcpy(output, "hello");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that's done it! I was getting confused with my `&` and `*` in the calling function too. In the calling function the var is defined as `unsigned char *` and is prefixed with a `&` in the function call. Within `encryptTake2:` all references to the var are prefixed with `*`. I need to re-read chapter 5 of the C book.