# How do I use "getHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:"?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uicolor

There's this method in UIColor in iOS 5:

```
- (BOOL)getHue:(CGFloat *)hue saturation:(CGFloat *)saturation brightness:(CGFloat *)brightness alpha:(CGFloat *)alpha
```

But i don't understand how i'm meant to use that in code. Surely i don't need to be stating each of those components if i'm looking to get that out of the UIColor?

Comment: Please make it a point to study this when posting on the site http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help Don't make us clean up your code every single time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
CGFloat hue;
CGFloat saturation;
CGFloat brightness;
CGFloat alpha;

[aColor getHue:&hue 
    saturation:&saturation 
    brightness:&brightness 
         alpha:&alpha];    
//now the variables hold the values
```

`getHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:` returns a bool, determining, if the UIColor could had been converted at all.

Example:

```
BOOL b = [[UIColor colorWithRed:.23 green:.42 blue:.9 alpha:1.0] getHue:&hue saturation:&saturation brightness:&brightness alpha:&alpha];
NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f %d", hue, saturation, brightness, alpha, b);
```

will log `0.619403 0.744444 0.900000 1.000000 1`, as it is valid

while

```
BOOL b = [[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pattern.png"]] getHue:&hue saturation:&saturation brightness:&brightness alpha:&alpha];
NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f %d", hue, saturation, brightness, alpha, b);
```

logs `0.000000 0.000000 -1.998918 0.000000 0`. The last 0 is the Bool, so this is not valid, and actually `brightness can only range from 0.0 to 1.0`, but here it holds some random crap.

### Conclusion

The code should be something like

```
CGFloat hue;
CGFloat saturation;
CGFloat brightness;
CGFloat alpha;

if([aColor getHue:&hue saturation:&saturation brightness:&brightness alpha:&alpha]){
    //do what ever you want to do if values are valid
} else {
    //what needs to be done, if converting failed? 
    //Some default values? raising an exception? return?
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Notice that those four parameters are *pointers* to `CGFloat`s, not just values. This is standard C pass-by-reference. See also the following Stack Overflow questions:

- [Rewriting a returned pointer to an output parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856383/rewriting-a-returned-pointer-to-an-output-parameter)
- [Use of pass by reference in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249040/use-of-pass-by-reference-in-objective-c)
- [passing out parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020977/passing-out-parameter)

As an example:

```
CGFloat hue, saturation, brightness, alpha;
[myColor getHue:&hue saturation:&saturation brightness:&brightness alpha:&alpha];
// hue, saturation, brightness, and alpha are now set
```